# Django image field not retrived from storage

Tags: python, django, imagefield, media-url

I plot a graph and save it as an image in my model. But, the file is not getting retrived at html page. My models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
      ... 
      ...
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='graphs',blank=True)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")

MEDIA_URL =  "/media/"
```

The file is  getting stored in the media/graphs directory. `{{ MyModel.photo.url }}` is printed correctly as `/media/graphs/file_name`. But when put in an image tag, it is not getting displayed. Why is this happening so?

Answer (score 0):

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"/media/")
```

evals to `/media/`, because `/media/`is already an absolute path. You want

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")
```

Comment: Now the image is stored at the place. But for retriving it? I use `{{ MyModel.photo.url }}` in the img tag. But the image is not displayed

Comment: Please read django's doc - there's a part about serving media files with the dev server.